# Haskell: Why does derivingSafeCopy depend only on the types passed into the Constructor?

Tags: haskell, serialization, database-migration

I want to use derivingSafeCopy from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy-0.9.0.1/docs/Data-SafeCopy.html , for serializing my data types to store them in a Database -- this is because I want to be able to migrate types in my database easily.

According to the specs, if I have something like:

```
data A = A
data B = B
deriveSafeCopy 1 'base ''A
deriveSafeCopy 1 'base ''B
```

the output of putCopy A and putCopy B will be identical. I would hope that putCopy A and putCopy B would be different, since I'm serializing A and B using runGet . safeGet, and want A and B would serialize to something different. Why does it work this way, and how can I get A and B to serialie to different things in a way that will allow me to migrate data types easily?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the data was tagged with the serialized type, as you seem to think it should. How would you use this information? Even if it were possible to deserialize a value without specifying the type, how would you use the resulting value (you don't know its type, after all).

Consider making a type like this:

```
data C = TagA A | TagB B
```

Now you can put `A` and `B` values in a `C` *wrapper* and serialize the result. When you deserialize values of type `C`, you now have a tag (the constructor) to indicate the type of the contained value.

Disclaimer: I have never had an occasion to use these libraries.